# How do I update / reinstall the normal version of Skype for Windows 10, not the Microsoft Store version?

Tags: windows-10, skype

I opened Skype and it started installing an update, which I cancelled out of habit. Then I tried to open Skype again, and it wouldn't work, it came up with this error message:

[image]

And it simply won't open. I have to use the Microsoft Store version. But I prefer the original version. I've tried searching online to find a way to update or reinstall it, but everything points me to the Microsoft Store, which I don't want.

Is there a way to update/reinstall the original version of Skype on Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Skype for Desktop application, which is distinct from the now "standard" Skype client which most download links will get you.

[image]

It can be found at [Download Skype for Windows, Mac or Linux](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/download-skype-for-desktop/)

This solution appears to work on Microsoft Edge, Firefox (desktop version), and Samsung internet (Chrome based) on Android, but for some reason not Google Chrome where it instead offers you the Windows Store version. In Chrome the button link goes to the Microsoft Store so if it appears not to work then try a different browser, use the change below or get a useragent switcher in Chrome to impersonate a different browser for this site.

In Chrome it shows you this instead

[image]

and clicking the link sends you to the Windows Store 
[image]

In Chrome (or any other browser which sends you to the Windows Store) you need to click the dropdown arrow next to "Get Skype for Windows 10" and select just "Get Skype for Windows"

[image]

Comment: That just brings me to the Microsoft Store, which is the version I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Lou - Worked for me.  Allowed me to download an executable

Comment: So I see a button that says "Get Skype for Windows 10". Then I click on the link, and it goes to the Microsoft Store, and takes me to that version of Skype. I don't see a way to download an .exe

Comment: @Lou - On Windows 10 1809, using Edge, when I click on the link I download an exectuable.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, I was using Chrome. I tried using Edge and, just as you said, it lets me download an executable. Thanks, I'll see if it works :)

Comment: Yup, can confirm that this has installed the version I wanted on my computer :). Have suggested an edit to this answer mentioning that it worked from Edge but not Chrome, as that seemed to be the issue I was having.

Comment: @Lou I've accepted and added more details. Not sure why Chrome is singled out as the "must show a different page" but there are workarounds at least.

Comment: @Lou found out why, the dropdown has another version shown by Chrome, you want the "Get Skype for Windows" and not "Get Skype for Windows 10" which is selected by default. The little arrow on the right of the download button is clickable.

Comment: Ahh, it makes sense! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It is interesting, using Edge in emulation mode, I verified Chrome is the only browser that gives an option for `Skype for Windows 10` on the Desktop tab.  Every other browser only shows `Get Skype for Windows` and the `Skype for Windows 10` option only appears on the Tablet tab.